# How to get the value of a variable from another class in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, function, dart, variables

I'm confused how to access the value of the variable "city" in the class below. I want to put the value of the the return result of this class into a list of string. Any directions?

```
class DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  Future<void> playvideo(YoutubePlayerController controller, int second) {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: second), () => controller.play());
  }

  Future<String?> determinePosition(
    BuildContext context,
  ) async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error(
        // ignore: lines_longer_than_80_chars
        'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.',
      );
    }

    final location = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();

    final locator =
        await placemarkFromCoordinates(location.latitude, location.longitude);
    final city = locator[0].subAdministrativeArea;
    print(city);
    final listcity = city!.split(' ');
    if (listcity[0] == 'Kota' || listcity[0] == 'Kabupaten') {
      // ignore: unawaited_futures, use_build_context_synchronously
      BlocProvider.of<DetailCubit>(context).getdetail(
        judul: widget.judulTahunArgument.judul,
        tahun: widget.judulTahunArgument.tahun,
        city: listcity[1],
      );
      return listcity[1];
    }
    else if (listcity[1] == 'City') {
      // ignore: unawaited_futures, use_build_context_synchronously
      BlocProvider.of<DetailCubit>(context).getdetail(
        judul: widget.judulTahunArgument.judul,
        tahun: widget.judulTahunArgument.tahun,
        city: listcity[0],
      );
      return listcity[0];
    }
    else {
      final city = locator[0].administrativeArea!;

      // ignore: unawaited_futures, use_build_context_synchronously
      BlocProvider.of<DetailCubit>(context).getdetail(
        judul: widget.judulTahunArgument.judul,
        tahun: widget.judulTahunArgument.tahun,
        city: city,
      );
      return city;
    }
  }
```

I want to put the value of the variable "city" into this list of string,bcs i want to use this list for a dropdownlist button.

```
  List <String> cities = [
      $City, "Ambon", "Bali", "Balikpapan", "Bandung", "Bangka", "Banjar", "Banjarbaru",
      "Banjarmasin", "Banjarnegara", "Banyuwangi", "Batam", "Batu", "Baturaja",
      "Bau bau","Bekasi", "Bengkulu", "Binjai", "Bitung", "Blitar", "Bogor",
      "Bojonegoro", "Bondowoso", "Bone", "Ciamis", "Cikarang", "Cilacap", "Cilegon",
      "Cirebon", "Demak", "Depok", "Dumai", "Duri", "Garut", "Gorontalo", "Gresik",
      "Jakarta"
];
```

Btw, they are on the same file. Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Does `$DetailPageState().determinePosition()` work?

Comment: I just tried it, but it does not work :(